# remove R Dataframe rows based on zero values in one column

Tags: r, dataframe, delete-row

I have this dataframe with a set of zero values along two columns. df

```
 Sl_No  No_of_Mails No_of_Responses
 1       10           2
 2        0           0
 3       20           0
 4       10          10
 5        0           0
 6        0          NA
 7       10          NA
 8       10           0
```

I want to remove those rows where `No_of_Mails` equals zero without disturbing the other column. 
I have tried the following code

```
row_sub = apply(df, 1, function(row) all(row !=0 ))
df[row_sub,]
```

This removes all the 0 values including the one from the `number_of_responses` column. I wish to have that column undisturbed
I have also tried this

```
 df[df$No_of_Mails][!(apply(df, 1, function(y) any(y == 0))),].
```

This deletes all the rows and gives me a table with zero rows.

Comment: Why not `df[df$No_of_Mails != 0, ]` ?

Comment: NEat. Its a subset function. and more compact than the ones I tried.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just subset the data frame based on the value in the `No_of_Mails` column:

```
df[df$No_of_Mails != 0, ]
```

### Demo